# Schema for many to many in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, schema

Now i have 3 tables which are:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS experience(
   experience_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   salarie_id int(11),
   consultant_id int(11),
   post varchar(255),
   entreprise_name varchar(255),
   start_time varchar(255),
   end_time varchar(255),
   description varchar(10000),
   PRIMARY KEY(experience_id)
 );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS salarie(
   salarie_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name varchar(255),
   PRIMARY KEY(salarie_id)
 );
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS consultant(
   consultant_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   nom varchar(255),
   PRIMARY KEY(consultant_id)
 );
```

The context: A `salarie` can have different `experience`s and a `consultant` can have different `experience`s. But `salarie` and `consultant` are different roles.

I think i should modify `experience` table because it has two columns `salarie_id int(11), consultant_id int(11)`.

What should i do?

Edit:

I think it's one-to-many relationship. Because one consultant/salarie can have as many as experiences, and one experience only belongs to one consultant/salarie. Am I right?

But I think the table experience shouldn't contain columns  salarie_id int(11) and consultant_id int(11), at the same time.

What do you think?

And if it's a many-to-many relationship. What about the breif following designing?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS consultant{
    c_id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    primary key(c_id)
}

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS salarie{
    s_id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    primary key(s_id)
}    
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS experience{ 
    e_id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    primary key(e_id)
}

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  salarie_experience{
    se_id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    s_id int(10),
    e_id int(10),
    primary key(se_id),
    foreign key(s_id) references salarie(s_id) on delete cascade,
    foreign key(e_id) references experience(e_id) on delete cascade
}    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS consultant_experience
    ce_id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    c_id int(10),
    e_id int(10),
    primary key(ce_id),
    foreign key(c_id) references consultant(c_id) on delete cascade,
    foreign key(e_id) references experience(e_id) on delete cascade
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you give an example of a row in salarie?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that an experience can belong to more than one consultant or salaire. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I just want to one consultant or salarie can own several experiences, and one experience only belongs to one consultant or salarie.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, you want salarie and consultant to be able to have many experiences but one particular experience should not belong to several different consultants/salaries. Therefore, I think you designed it correctly but perhaps you should set foreign key constraints on salarie_id and consultant_id in the experience table.

However, it might be so that you rather have employees which in turn have roles. For example:

[alt text http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/9437/picture4ik.png](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/9437/picture4ik.png)

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table employe
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employe ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employe (
  idemploye INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  nom VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (idemploye) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table experience
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS experience ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS experience (
  experience_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  employe_idemploye INT NOT NULL ,
  post VARCHAR(255) ,
  entreprise_name VARCHAR(255) ,
  start_time VARCHAR(255) ,
  end_time VARCHAR(255) ,
  description VARCHAR(10000) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (experience_id, employe_idemploye) ,
  INDEX fk_experience_employe (employe_idemploye ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT fk_experience_employe
    FOREIGN KEY (employe_idemploye )
    REFERENCES employe (idemploye ));


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table role
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS role ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS role (
  idrole INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  employe_idemploye INT NOT NULL ,
  nom VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (idrole, employe_idemploye) ,
  INDEX fk_role_employe (employe_idemploye ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT fk_role_employe
    FOREIGN KEY (employe_idemploye )
    REFERENCES employe (idemploye ))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: @leson, thanks a lot for your suggestion. But i didn't find the table consultant in your solution. What can i do for that table?

Comment: @garcon1986: The idea is to turn both salaire and consultant into rows in the Role table. Then you create employees which have one or more roles (perhaps there are more roles than salaire/consultant that an employee can have?) and one or more experiences.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood correctly, this is an M:M relation ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29 ) and you need a junction table or tables, like consultant_experience(consultant_id, experience_id)

Comment: @thanks stereofrog, but i think it's a one-to-many relationship.
because one consultant/salarie can have as many as experiences, and one experience only belongs to one consultant/salarie. Am I right?

Comment: if a consultant and/or salaries has several experiences. How can i handle this?